# Singular or Plural nouns

Tags: plural-forms, singular

Could someone please help me with this sentence? I’m having problem with deciding if it’s it should be plural or singular.

> I have a blue and red car.

or

> I have a blue and red cars.

Which one is correct? I think it should be car and not cars as we are only talking about one unit.

Comment: Well... do you have one car that is blue and one car that is red for a total of two cars or do you have one car that is both blue and red?

Comment: Related: [Plural or singular noun when it refers to two things in a list](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/221331/plural-or-singular-noun-when-it-refers-to-two-things-in-a-list)

Answer (score 2):

In your example, you will want to use the singular, I believe you are trying to say

> I have a blue car and a red car.
>   I have a blue and a red car.
>   *I have two cars, one is red and one is blue*

The article "a" distinguishes the two different cars.

However, your example

> I have a blue and red car.

can mean you have one car and it has blue and red coloring.

> I have blue and red cars.

means you have at least one blue car and at least one red car, but may have several of each.

Comment: The general answer under the link given in comments, http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/221331/plural-or-singular-noun-when-it-refers-to-two-things-in-a-list , is that you *can't* say "I have a blue and a red car", and should say "I have a blue car and a red one". Isn't it?